# mlr Package in R, makeLearner mtry default value

Tags: r, machine-learning, mlr

What is the mtry default value in function makeLearner() from mlr package? If I don't specify my mtry parameter like the code below, what is the mtry default value? Thank you!

I cannot really find the answer at the mlr website.

```
makeLearner("classif.ranger", precit.type ="prob", num.trees = 500, min.node.size = 1000, importance = 'impurity', seed = 123, verbose = TRUE, num.threads = parallel::detectCores())
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the default the `ranger` package uses:

> Default is the (rounded down) square root of the number variables.